# Why doesn't Linux cache object and/or ".so" files when using GNU Linker?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, ld

When linking executables (more than 200) in a large project, I get link rate 0.5 executables per second, even if I have ran the link stage a minute before. vmstat shows more than 20MB/s disk read rate.

But if I pre-cache the build directory using "tar cf /dev/null build-dir" once, I get consistent link rate of 4.8 executables per second and the disk read rate is basically zero.

Why doesn't Linux cache the object files and/or ".so" files when they are read by GNU Linker, but does so when they are read by tar? There is plenty of RAM (16GB). Kernel version is 4.4.146. CentOS 7.5.

Comment: Do you use a hard disk, not an SSD?

Comment: Yes, the build-dir is on a plain hard disk currently. It used to be on SSD, but I moved it away to spread disk load during builds, as the computer became unresponsive. I suppose the caching algorithm is the same for SSD, so the cause for unresponsiveness was the same caching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an incorrect setting of *vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1000* was causing this misbehaviour. Setting it to 70 fixed the problem and restored good cache performance.

And the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) explicitly recommends against increasing the value beyond 100. Unfortunately, the Internet is full of examples with insane values like 1000.